# отправка потока видео MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, mvc

Появилась нужда в стриме видео. При отправке потока маленького видео всё впорядке, но когда отправляется видео по 20 минут и больше, выдаёт `OutOfMmemoryException.`
Контроллер

```
public class VideoController : Controller
{
    // GET: Video
    public FileStreamResult Index()
    {
        Stream fileStream = System.IO.File.Open(@"F:\Мусор\Test.mp4", FileMode.Open);

        return new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "video/mp4");//Исключение
    }
    public PartialViewResult GetPlayer()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

Представление:

```
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/scripts/jquery.jplayer.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#jpId").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    m4v: '@Url.Action("Index")'
                }).jPlayer("play");
            },
            supplied: "m4v",
            swfPath: "jPlayer/js"
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="jpId"></div>
```

Может есть способ разбить поток на несколько равных частей. Или другое решение
З.Ы. Использовался плагин **JPlayer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileStreamResult` это не стриминг в чистом его виде, а просто чтение файла + отправка клиенту. Чистый ASP.NET MVC на данный момент стриминг не поддерживает.

Если нужен стриминг - перенесите этот метод в контроллер ASP.NET WebAPI и возвращайте `StreamContent` / `PushStreamContent` - они оба отключают буферизацию и шлют данные по мере чтения из стрима / пуша в стрим.

Comment: Надо посмотреть реализацию. Такое ощущение что там достаточно попросту отключить буферизацию...